# PyQt5 fails to open window while shell code executing

Tags: python, subprocess, pyqt5

I have PyQt application and main window. When I try to execute shell code and open new window in order to display the status of execution(sort of loading bar), new window doesn't work properly: it fails to display elements and gets stuck or simply closes.
Here example of my code:

```
class Command(object):
    ...
    def executeCommand(self):
        self.loading = LoadWindow()
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
        self.proc.communicate()
        self.loading.close()

class Plugin(QWidget):
    ...
    def run(self):
        ...
        cmd = Command()
        cmd.makeCommand()
        cmd.executeCommand()
        return

class LoadWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(20, 20, 160, 20)
        self.pbar.setRange(0,0)
        self.pbar.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Cancel', self)
        self.btn.setGeometry(70, 50, 60, 20)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.Cancel)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 80)
        self.setWindowTitle('Loading...')
        self.show()
```

I tried to add some delay after calling new window and open new window in new thread, but got the same result. If I call LoadWindow() without subrocess in main loop, it works correctly.

Comment: show complete code please

Comment: @eyllanesc done

Comment: what's self.cmd, cmd.makeCommand(), please, complete code

Comment: @eyllanesc makeCommand() just reutrns the sting which represents a shell command(self.cmd). In my case, this command just changes dir and launches another project: cmd = "cd;cd project; ./run > test.txt". In fact, shell code works well, and I get right result in test.txt file.

Comment: @NikitaRock. Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].